# Adding and retrieving Data sets to Redis using StackExchange.Redis

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

Am new to Redis. I am able to store and retrieve data to redis using this commands

```
hmset user:user1 12 13 14 15
```

and also am to retrieve data by

```
hgetall user:user1
```

i want to do the same using stackExchange.redis on my c# program. 
how should i do this in c#?

Comment: Have you seen the documentation on https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis ?

Comment: yes, but cant find an exact method suitable for my case

Comment: this is what i tried so far, HashEntry[] hashfield = new HashEntry[4] // contains hash entries,  redisDB.HashSet("user",hashfield);

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To set multiple values in a hash you can call the following HashSet method overload:

```
ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost");
IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();
db.HashSet("user:user1", new HashEntry[] { new HashEntry("12", "13"), new HashEntry("14", "15") });
```

Comment: I guess it makes sense that the documentation for StackExchange.Redis be on stackoverflow.com...